# BinaryReader.ReadChars behavior different between .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 6 but docs identical

Tags: c#, .net

This simple Console app has a different behavior when compiled / run on .NET 6.0 vs .NET Core 3.1. However, the documentation for `BinaryReader.ReadChars` is identical:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleAppNet1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
            using var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            using var reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
            stream.Position = 8;    // Past end of stream
            try
            {
                var chars = reader.ReadChars(2);
                // NET Core 3.1 writes this line:
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception was not thrown. {chars.Length} chars read.");
            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
            {
                // NET Core 6.0 writes this line:
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"ArgumentOutOfRangeException was thrown: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.NET Core 3.1 output:

```
Exception was not thrown. 0 chars read.
```

.NET 6.0 output:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException was thrown: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
```

I would expect the behavior to be identical on .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 6.0 but this particular method returns an empty array on .NET Core 3.1 and throws an exception on .NET 6.0.

What am I missing? :)
Thanks!

Comment: One possibility is that the implementation of that method hasn't changed but the implementation of a method it calls has changed. It might be worth digging into the source for each version to see what's different.

Comment: To help you get started with user18387401's suggestion: [current ReadChars implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/38ca26b27b9e7a867e6ff69eec3cabbfb4e9e1cf/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/BinaryReader.cs#L420) vs [3.1 ReadChars implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/v3.1.27/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/BinaryReader.cs#L474).

Comment: Thanks @user18387401, @DiplomacyNotWar. The implementation of `InternalReadChars` which is called from `ReadChars` has changed between 3.1 and 6.0. This seems to be the cause of the different behavior. Not sure there's much I can do about it. While we all agree that the developer should be careful and test for such situations, this could be considered a breaking change I guess.

Comment: I'd recommend opening an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues), because this looks like a plain old bug. The method is only documented to return `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` for negative input, and it isn't reasonable to throw in this particular case (if it had to be considered an error at all, I'd expect an `IOException` or at worst an `InvalidOperationException`). There is an [open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/68139) discussing the desired semantics for `BinaryReader`; this is not the same thing but definitely related.